# Efficiently Group a date list

Tags: group

I have a list of dates which are grouped by year and date and also checks if there is a entry in that year:

```
{% set allSubmissions = craft.amForms.submissions(
  {
    formHandle: 'reservation',
    limit: null,
    order: 'datum asc',
  })
%} {# Gets all the entries #}

{% set izgrad = now | date('Y-m-d') %} {# format now #}
{% set alteAnmeldung = allSubmissions.dateCreated | date('Y') %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allSubmissions | group("datum.year") %}

  {% if year >= alteAnmeldung %} {# only show the current and future year #}

    <h3>{{ year }}</h3>
    <ul>
      {% for month, entriesInMonth in entriesInYear | group("datum|date('m')") %}
          {% for day, entriesInDay in entriesInMonth | group("datum|date('d')") %}
            {% for item in entriesInDay %}
              {% if loop.first %}
                {% if izgrad <= item.datum %}
                  <li><a href="#{{ item.datum }}">{{ item.datum | date('d.m.Y') }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This works and the list looks like this:

[image]

But the code looks horribly inefficient. (this creates 74 db queries). I think there must be a better way to write this. Is it possible to group the fields with less steps for example?